# MySQL index for datetime column with frequent MAX() queries?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I have a SQL query in MySQL 8 to get the latest date in a column, and a count of all records in the table:

`SELECT max(ModificationTimestamp) as lastUpdate, count(*) as total FROM mls_data;`

There are about 3 million rows in the table, and the query takes almost 30 seconds to execute.

How can I make this query execute faster? Index? Config settings? Increase InnoDB buffers?

Comment: create separate table and updated via trigger

Comment: `MAX(ModificationTimestamp)` should already be fast if you have an index on that column. The problem is that `COUNT(*)` is slow in InnoDB -- it doesn't keep the count anywhere, so it has to scan the entire table.

Comment: @Barmar count(*) doesn't have to scan the entire table, it can scan an entire index instead.

Comment: @ysth It has to scan something. The total isn't stored anywhere.

Comment: please edit your question to show (as text, not images) output of `show create table mls_data;` and `explain select max(ModificationTimestamp) as lastUpdate, count(*) as total FROM mls_data;` and `explain select count(*) as total FROM mls_data;`.  also tell us how long just `select count(*) as total FROM mls_data` takes

Comment: @Barmar right, but if you have an index on a low cardinality field, it can be much faster than a full table scan

Comment: The smaller the index is, the better (think I/O); cardinality does not matter.

Answer (score 0):

Just add an index on that column, and MAX() query will be quick:

```
create index modificationtimestamp_idx on mls_data(ModificationTimestamp)
```

Your problem, though, can be with `count(*)`, so test with and without count(*).
You can do the trick and create a schedule that will update some stats table every 5 minutes with count and max if you don't need real-time results.

Comment: The `COUNT(*)` will still have to scan some index, possibly your suggested index.